# What are some of the lesser known practices you follow that set you apart from the average developer?

Tags: open-source, article

People say practicing and keeping up to date with the latest technologies makes you a good developer, but what are some lesser known practices you all can suggest for someone currently doing a Bachelor's degree in Software Engineering and wants to stand out in their Master's application abroad?

I've started writing technical articles on Medium, finding open source contributions (which I rarely find for beginner level and any suggestions would be appreciated) and doing coding challenges online. Is there anything else I should be focusing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've got plenty of time. keep learning technologies you're interested in, do projects and develop your skills along the way I'd say. Participate in competitions if you can. Open source contribution is a pretty good step